# BigQuery Standard SQL using UNNEST duplicates the data

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using Bigquery standard sql to count google analytics data, but when i apply unnest to break repeated record field in table, other columns like hit count data become duplicate and display more value than the actual

```
SELECT
    date,
    trafficSource.source as source,
    trafficSource.medium as medium,
    SUM(totals.hits) AS total_hit,
    MAX(hits.transaction.transactionid) as transaction
FROM
    `test.test.session_streaming_*`,unnest(hits) hits
WHERE
    _table_suffix BETWEEN '20180401'
    AND '20180501'   
GROUP BY
    date,
    trafficSource.source,
    trafficSource.medium
```

Could anyone help me to tell how can we remove duplicate data in this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to compute the max transaction ID within `hits` for each row, and then take the max across all rows. This should work:

```
SELECT
  date,
  trafficSource.source as source,
  trafficSource.medium as medium,
  SUM(totals.hits) AS total_hit,
  MAX((SELECT MAX(transaction.transactionid) FROM UNNEST(hits))) as transaction
FROM
  `test.test.session_streaming_*`
WHERE
  _table_suffix BETWEEN '20180401'
    AND '20180501'
GROUP BY
  date,
  trafficSource.source,
  trafficSource.medium
```